# Cannot use IBExpert after updating to Firebird 4.0

Tags: firebird, ibexpert, firebird-4.0

IBExpert has a user database which stores all options. I made a FBK backup of this database using Firebird 2.5 which was my old level. I installed Firebird 4.0 and restored it. Now I have this database under both ODS levels (I believe that would be 12.0 and 14.0).

Initially I placed the 64-bit fbclient.dll file in the IBExpert path. It threw an error message that the 32-bit DLL was required. No problem, I switched it out. It will not connect to the user database which means I've lost 100+ DB registrations. When the newer ODS level copy didn't work, I tried the old one just in case some Firebird embedded logic was in place.

I also cannot initialize a new database from the options menu. Message below.

Versions: Firebird 4.0.2 64-bit, IBExpert 2023.3.5.1

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Note - all other applications that use Firebird are up and running fine including apps built in Delphi and in C#.

I tried something new, backing up my IBExpert database using Firebird 2.5 32-bit, then restoring it using Firebird 2.5 64-bit. From here I backed it up again and restored with Firebird 4.0.2 64-bit. This time I was told my username and password were not defined. I can connect with ISQL so I know these values to be good. I added Legacy_Auth and WIN_Sspi to the AuthServer config, Legacy_UserManager to the UserManager. Still no luck.

[image]

Comment: If you now get _"Your user name and password are not defined"_, then either you're using the wrong user name and password, or IBExpert for example only tries the legacy_auth authentication (e.g. because the fbclient.dll you selected is from Firebird 2.5), and your user only exists for Srp (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

If your user database is not shared and you are not going to use it from different computer - just don't mess with it. IBExpert will happily use bundled Firebird 2.5 embedded library for it.

If you want the database to be shared and kept on Firebird 4 - don't use local connection string in shown dialog. Use TCP connection string.